# block screen sharing via USB or Miracast from windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am working on a media Windows Phone 8 app that has lot of video content that cannot be viewed on other screens than the phone. Basically the client doesn't have the right to make the videos available on screens bigger than 13" and asked if we can block screen sharing via usb or miracast when we use the app. 
Does anyone know if this is possible in Windows phone, i've looked in the documentation and can't find the information. We have developped the same app for IPhone and we can block screen sharing on the iPhone app, any clue how to do this for Windows Phone?

Answer (score 0):

I wondered if Miracast can be used for Windows 8 or Windows phone 8?